# Header link overlapping issue

Tags: css, z-index, css-position

http://ajaxstudios.com/

The floating animated "Game of the Day" link is extended OVER the Quick Ventrilo Connection button and even over the sub header text.

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to accomplish that isn't so messy? I'm using mainly top: and padding: to position the text right now. I've also tried using a higher z-index on the ventrilo connect buttons to have it layered above the link, but it doesn't seem to be working...

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks for your time.

-Ethan/Otoris

Answer (score 0):

instead of padding on the game of the day link, use right or left, since you're already using absolute positioning. 
in correlation, if i understand correctly, to make the buttons layered above the link, you need to apply position:relative or absolute in order to get z-index stacking to work.

Comment: The problem with me using left or right CSS is that when the window changes size, the position of the element gets screwed up, unlike using top. I did fix the z-index though, thanks.

Comment: you could add a wrapper element (i know that sucks) and set position relative to it, i think.